# Invoke methods of a class that has dependency injection C# .NET Core 6.0

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0, ihttpclientfactory

I have a controller in C# that invokes a class, which in turn makes HTTP requests and returns its response, according to the code sequence below:

I added the following line in `Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
```

I created a class that receives the controller invocation and makes the HTTP request to the external website.

```
public class Users
{
    public async Task<string> GetUsers(HttpClient _httpClient )
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("get"), "https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/users");

        var res = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);

        var content = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return content;
    }
}
```

I created a controller to receive my HTTP requests, and this controller instantiates a client through the `IHttpClientFactory`, with the aim of avoiding exhaustion of HTTP sockets...

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _client;

    public UsersController(IHttpClientFactory client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public class UsersModel
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string gender { get; set; }
        public string status {  get; set; }
    }

    [HttpGet("GetUsers")]
    public async Task<List<UsersModel>> GetUsers()
    {
        var myClient = _client.CreateClient();
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UsersModel>>(await new Users().GetUsers(myClient));
    }
}
```

Ok, the code sequence above does the job correctly, but there is one thing that bothers me a lot, which is this dependency injection and creation of an HTTP client in each controller that calls this class.

I would like to create a class that accepts being invoked by the controller, but this class itself creates its HTTP client, without it having to be passed as a parameter by the controller...

I tried something like this: I modified my controller to no longer have dependency injection, but just invoke the class:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    public class UsersModel
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string gender { get; set; }
        public string status {  get; set; }
    }

    [HttpGet("GetUsers")]
    public async Task<List<UsersModel>> GetUsers()
    {
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UsersModel>>(await new Users().GetUsers());
    }
}
```

The class, in turn, would be responsible for creating the HTTP client.

```
public class Users
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _client;

    public Users(IHttpClientFactory client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetUsers()
    {
        var _httpClient = _client.CreateClient();
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("get"), "https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/users");

        var res = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);

        var content = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return content;
    }
}
```

But I now get this error:
[image: there is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter...]

I've seen some people saying that they have to implement a constructor, insert a `: base()`... but I confess that I'm not at a sufficient level to solve this problem on my own. I would really appreciate it if anyone can help me with this task.

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with your code:

1. dependency injection: all items in the service pool should be a **service**. Your `Users` class is actually a service, but obviously you did not register your service into DI. This often occurs in Program.cs (or .NET Core 3 and below, in StartUp). And should be like this:

```cs
builder.Services.AddTransient<Users>(); // Transient due to HttpClient
```

Besides, a service class usually have the name convention: `XxxService`. And usually has an Interface behind it for best practice of DI. but no big deal for your case.

2. You can directly inject the `HttpClient` into `Users`, not the factory. You already have DI, it will handle the instantiation of `HttpClient`.
3. After you register your service into DI, you can call it from your Controller:

```cs
private readonly Users _users; // here no more HttpClient since you injected it into Users.

    public UsersController(Users users)
    {
        _users= users;
    }
```

3. Your `GetUsers` method in the service should be like this:

```cs
public async Task<string> GetUsersAsync() // async method should end up with 'Async'
    {
        var _httpClient = _client.CreateClient(); // as mentioned in 2, you could directly use _httpClient, instead of create a new instance using factory pattern.

        var res = await _httpClient.GetAsync("https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/users");

        var content = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return content;
        // error handling?
    }
```

4. you inject your `Users` service into the Controller, just like how you inject the `HttpClient` into `Users`. and no more `new()`!

```cs
return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UsersModel>>(await _users.GetUsers()); // here _users is the instance of `Users` from DI
```

Please learn the basis before you contribute code for production.